# Moving image when wave hand in front of camera using opencv for android

Tags: android, opencv, camera, android-camera

i'm trying to implement like this in my application
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrXwJIco4w8

but it seems i don't really get the idea how to do it..

seems i must use motion tracking and hand recognition, also communicate with front-end camera, but mostly link that i found only show detect OUTSIDE object not INSIDE object(means inside device).

so what i want is if there is object(like image or anything) in application, then when i move my hand in front of camera like go to left, then the image position also go to left.
Make the image move without interact with touch but using camera instead(touchless)

Can you help me show way to do it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know about camera but I do have an alternative idea for using wave gestures to change image etc.
You can use the proximity sensor on the phone. But it cannot understand that you moved your hand from left to right or right to left. So, you can have something like this:

Moving once over sensor - left to right
Moving twice over sensor - right to left

You can define proximity sensor something like this:

```
public class ProximityNotifier implements SensorEventListener{

private final SensorManager mSensorManager;
private final Sensor mProximitySensor;
private final Sensor mAccelSensor;
private float mProximityMax = 0.0f;
private boolean mStartProxComparison;
public float mProximityValue = 0.0f;
private long lastBlockedTimestamp = 0;
private long gapPlayPause = 0;
private long gapNext = 0;
private static float mValue0 = 0.0f;
private static float mValue1 = 0.0f;
private ProximityNotifier.Callback cb = null;
private static final String TAG = "ProximityNotifier";

public ProximityNotifier(Context ctxt, ProximityNotifier.Callback cb, long gap1, long gap2) {

    this.cb = cb;
    this.gapPlayPause = gap1;
    this.gapNext = gap2;
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)ctxt.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mProximitySensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
    mAccelSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    if (null != mProximitySensor)
        mProximityMax = mProximitySensor.getMaximumRange();
    mProximityValue = mProximityMax;
    startProximityNotifier();
}



public interface Callback {
    void pageChange();        
}


public void startProximityNotifier() {
    if(null != mSensorManager) {
        if ((null != mProximitySensor) && (null != mAccelSensor)) {
            mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mProximitySensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
            mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
            mStartProxComparison = true;
        }
        else
            mStartProxComparison = false;
    }
}

public void stopProximityNotifier() {
    if(null != mSensorManager) {
        if ((null != mProximitySensor) && (null != mAccelSensor)) {
            mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mProximitySensor);
            mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mAccelSensor);
        }
    }
}

public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

    if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        mValue0 = sensorEvent.values[0];
        mValue1 = sensorEvent.values[1];
    }

    if ((sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) &&  
            ((mValue0 < 2) && (mValue0 > -2)) &&
            ((mValue1 < 2) && (mValue1 > -2))) { 
        // check for a max -> 0 transition
        if((mStartProxComparison == true) && ((mProximityValue == mProximityMax) && (sensorEvent.values[0] == 0))) {
            lastBlockedTimestamp = SystemClock.uptimeMillis(); 
        } 

        else { 
            long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            if (lastBlockedTimestamp != 0) {
                /*if ((now - lastBlockedTimestamp) > gapPlayPause) {
                    if (cb != null) {
                        //cb.gesturePlayPause();
                    }
                }else*/ if ((now - lastBlockedTimestamp) > gapNext){
                    if (cb != null)
                        cb.pageChange();
                }
            }

            lastBlockedTimestamp = 0;
        }
        mProximityValue = sensorEvent.values[0];
    }

}
```

}

and in your activity you can declare and use like this:

```
mProximityNotifier = new ProximityNotifier(this, this, 400, 200);

//Callback method for Proximity Sensor
    public void pageChange() {
        //call for image change
  }
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: your idea is great! but how to make it more different when left to right or right to left? if like that, it will make condition at least left to right first. can we make it little different so application will know if we want to go left or go right(also reset it)?

Comment: Proximity sensor senses light and it light is blocked, it triggers event. So, when hand is moved, we make a note of time. Now following things can be done: If hand is moved once in our defined time, we can say it as left to right. If we wave twice in defined time, we can say it right to left. We may hold our hand our sensor for 2 sec and can say it as pause. I have implemented pausing and changing song in my app "Fusion Music Player" . You can download and see.. I have also implemented waving once and twice for different action in other app and it works fine :)